# Separate "date and time" field in "date" and "time" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have a column with date and time (**yyyy/mm/dd hh/mm/ss**) as string. I have the date field already, but the hour field is empty. How can I transfer the hh/mm/ss part to the hour field?

I am new to QGIS (only have ArcGIS experience) and cannot code.

Comment: Is the date and time column a date and time field or is it a string?

Comment: String. It was given to me like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create 2 separate fields using the field calculator. Use this code for the date field:

> format_date(to_datetime( "date_as_string",'yyyy/MM/dd HH/mm/ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd')

And this code for the time field:

> format_date(to_datetime( "date_as_string",'yyyy/MM/dd HH/mm/ss'),'HH:mm:ss')

Result:

[image]

Also you can use this code to to store all the data in the single `datetime` field:

> format_date(to_datetime("date_as_string",'yyyy/MM/dd HH/mm/ss'),'yyyy/MM/dd HH/mm/ss')